# Error Bad origin on custom XCM integration

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, parachain, rust, xcm

I am building custom XCM pallet.

While executing specific call:

The destination is of ParaId type.

> ```
>       match send_xcm::<T::XcmSender>(
>           (Parent, Junction::Parachain(destination.into())).into(),
>           Xcm(vec![Transact {
>               origin_kind: OriginKind::Native,
>               require_weight_at_most: Weight::from_parts(1_000, 1_000),
>               call: <T as Config>::RuntimeCall::from(Call::<T>::mint_collection_received {
>                   collection_name,
>                   collection_description,
>                   origin_parachain_id: 2000.into(),
>                   owner: recipient.clone(),
>               })
>               .encode()
>               .into(),
>           }]),            ) {
>           Ok((hash, cost)) => Self::deposit_event(Event::CollectionCreatedAndTransferedXCM {
>               collection_hash,
>               owner: recipient.clone(),
>               destination,
>           }),
>           Err(e) => Self::deposit_event(Event::CollectionFailedToXCM {
>               e,
>               collection_hash,
>               owner: recipient.clone(),
>               destination,
>           }),             }
> ```

I receive error Bad Origin.
[image]
I execute it with sudo.

Any answer as to why?

Thanks

Once executed with normal test account I receive following output:
[image]
Any idea what "Transport" error mean?

Comment: can you provide:
1. the full sudo call screen?
2. xnftPallet extrinsic code?
3. your `xcm_executor::Config` details?
4. where (from which chain) are you trying to execute that sudo call?

Comment: Hey Branislav, I use the standard Parachain template so xcm_executor is default. I am calling this instruction from a locally launched parachain template via Zombienet. Do you mean the entire call of the xnft function?  The part I sent handles XCM, there is no other code to regard XCM in that function. Looking forward to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: > I execute it with sudo.

I just wanted to now "how and what did you execute exactly"? I mean, e.g. could you add screenshot with full extrinsic call from polkadot.js.org/apps or unit-test code snippet?

> "Transport" error

My guess is that you need to open HRMP channel to the `Parachain(2000)` at first.
E.g,. you can check hrmp channels like this:
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-bridge-hub-rpc.polkadot.io#/chainstate
`parachainSystem` -> `relevantMessagingState`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4080)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you could share your Zombienet, I could help better.

You can open HRMP channel but you need also sudo account on your local relay chain (I guess you have rococo-local?).

We have also some scripts for opening HRMP channel for our local testing with zombienet:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/zombienet/bridge-hubs/bridge_hub_rococo_local_network.toml
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/scripts/bridges_rococo_westend.sh#L211-L214
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/cumulus/scripts/bridges_common.sh#L165-L190

or with PJS:

[image]

Comment: Hey Branislav, here is code: https://github.com/ParaSpell-Research-Foundation/polkadot-sdk-nft-pallet/blob/master/cumulus/parachain-template/pallets/xnft/src/lib.rs

Comment: To test code pull the repo, then compile parachain template using
"cargo b -r -p parachain-template-node" then compile polkadot node using
"cd Polkadot && cargo build --release" , then launch via Zombienet: Navigate to binaries via "cd binaries" add your zombienet binary and run the command: "./zombienet-macos -p native -c 1 spawn config.toml"

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the links,
the problem with sudo is now clear, you need to change `ensure_signed` -> `ensure_signed_or_root` here: https://github.com/ParaSpell-Research-Foundation/polkadot-sdk-nft-pallet/blob/master/cumulus/parachain-template/pallets/xnft/src/lib.rs#L260C14-L260C27

Answer (score 0):

@dudo, can you please point me to the valid/compilable code, because I don't see setting [XcmSender here](https://github.com/ParaSpell-Research-Foundation/polkadot-sdk-nft-pallet/blob/master/cumulus/parachain-template/pallets/xnft/src/mock.rs#L94-L104), but [here](https://github.com/ParaSpell-Research-Foundation/polkadot-sdk-nft-pallet/blob/master/cumulus/parachain-template/pallets/xnft/src/lib.rs#L76) it is expected.

Without valid XcmConfig I cannot check that second isssue with `Transact`. I need to see XcmSender code :)

Comment: Hey @Branislav, I have not yet implemented XcmSender to mock.rs only to Runtime. You can compile the Parachain template with the commands I sent in a comment where I sent a link for the code.

Comment: I see, ok, so you are starting zombienet with two parachains (1000 and 1001) here https://github.com/ParaSpell-Research-Foundation/polkadot-sdk-nft-pallet/blob/master/binaries/config.toml#L21-L29. But in your example you use destination=2000. Also the runtime uses XcmRouter with XcmpQueue. So, if you want send XCM between parachain from 1000 -> 1001 you need to open HRMP channel between paras (as I said in the previous comments) and change destination to 2000.